# delete JSON which match to another JSON javascript angularjs json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

JSON A ['711','722','733','744']

JSON B [{pid: 711, name: 'hello'},{pid: 733, name: 'world'}, {pid: 713, name: 'hello'},{pid: 744, name: 'hellosdaf'}]

try to delte array B which is match to JSON A. like JSON B 711, 733, 744 is match to array to JSON A, i want to delete them.

i try the following function but not working which always have one or two string are miss delete.

```
        angular.forEach(B, function(value, index){
              if(A.indexOf(value.pid) > -1){
             B.splice(index , 1);

        }
        });
```

Comment: You are using index to delete an entry.  Whenever you delete an item, the index got rearranged.  Instead of removing from B, push the non matching element to a new array.

Comment: thank you for point out my problem

Answer (score 1):

loop through array A and then filter array B by using filter function
and use iterator function and return only function that key "pid" doesn't match.

```
for(var c of A){
  B = B.filter(function(n){
    return n.pid !== parseInt(c)
  });
}
```

hope this helps